# How do I set a delay and repeat the console.log every 1.5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html

So i've been writing some code and I ran into a problem with my while true loops, so this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dash miner</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log("Dash Mining Software (DMS)")

      function calculateHash(length) {
        var result = '';
        var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
      }
      function miner() {
          while (true) {
              console.log("Dash > " + calculateHash(128));
          }
      } 
      miner()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the problem is how can i repeat the;

```
      function miner() {
          while (true) {
              console.log("Dash > " + calculateHash(128));
          }
      }
```

loop every 1.5 seconds?

Comment: [`setInterval()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { miner(); }, 1500)`

Comment: @Zak  That won't solve his problem.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval() at the end of your script

for example

```
setInterval( miner, 1500 );
```

will repeat the miner() function every 1500 milliseconds (1.5 seconds)

Comment: You might want to also point out to the OP, that `while(true) {` also needs removing..

Comment: so like this?       setInterval( miner, 1500 );

      function miner() {
        console.log("Dash > " + calculateHash(128));
      } 
      miner() @Keith